# Orientação a Objeto - Flutter

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, flutter

Tenho um aplicativo em flutter que tem um formulario e que os dados sao enviados para uma classe, porem, tenho uma tela especifica que precisa recuperar um dados de classe em que eu enviei, mas quando eu recupero a variavel retorna null.

Envio do Dado:

```
Especialidade VarEspecialidade = new Especialidade();
VarEspecialidade.VariavelEspecialidade = DadosLista[index];
```

Classe que recebe os dados:

```
class Especialidade {

  String VariavelEspecialidade;
  Especialidade({this.VariavelEspecialidade});

}
```

Tela que eu chamo o dado:

```
class _Layout_Conclusao extends State<Layout_Conclusao>{

  Especialidade VarEspecialidade = new Especialidade();
  String Dados;

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Conclusão'),
        centerTitle: true,
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      body: Text(VarEspecialidade.VariavelEspecialidade.toString())
    );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como seu exemplo está meio cru e não tem como saber em que momento você preenche os dados, faça assim no local onde você alimenta a variável:

```
setState((){
  VarEspecialidade.VariavelEspecialidade = DadosLista[index];
});
```

Aconselho você estudar sobre State-management ou gerencia de estado em Flutter.